# How to make IE show more specific error?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a asp:FileUpload control in my page. The default file size is 4MB. If I tried to upload a file more than 4MB, I would get an Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. I put a breakpoint at the event handler for the upload, it didn't stop there. The error message is too general, is there anyway I could make IE show me more specific error message?

Update: I couldn't find a way to change the error message. I decided to use AJAX control AsyncFileUpload. It is a better version of the FileUpload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to handle this error is to increase the quota in web.config to some very large value and then inside your handler check the size of the uploaded file and if it is grater than 4MB display an error message:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- 10GB max file size -->
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```

Modern browsers that support the HTML 5 File API also allow you to check the file size on the client before even uploading it so you could show an error message to the user when he selects a file:

```
if (typeof FileReader !== 'undefined') {
    // the browser supports HTML 5 File API => we 
    // can check the size of the file that the user selected
    var size = document.getElementById('myfile').files[0].size;
    ...
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't work for 11GB files either and you'll processing files that are bigger than allowed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, no of course that it wouldn't. In this case define it to 20GB or whatever absolute maximum you have defined. Anyway, uploading 10GB files over HTTP is probably not something that you want to do anyway.

Comment: The webserver would have to process huge files only to say :"No sorry, too big".

Comment: @TimSchmelter, then use HTML 5 File API. And now you're gonna tell me what about those clients that use browsers that do not support the File API, you are simply out of luck. Don't worry, HTML 5 adoption in browsers quickly increases so this won't be a problem soon.

Comment: Do you mean you can only check the file size on the client side, not the server side?

Comment: @GaolaiPeng, no, you can check it on the server also. But only once the file gets uploaded to the server. And in order to be able to upload this file you will have to first modify your web.config and set the `maxRequestLength` setting to a value larger than the file you are trying to upload or ASP.NET will simply drop the request at a very early stage.

Comment: If I could not make IE show me more specific error, I have to do it myself. That means I have to check the file size before I upload it to the server. I checked the API you recommended, but I got JavaScript error. This is my code, var size1 = document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").files[0].size;  Can you tell me what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng, which version of IE are you using? Also make sure that you are calling this code only once the user has selected a file. You could for example subscribe to the onchange event of the file input or the onsubmit event of the form. If you call this javascript code in the beginning when the user hasn't selected a file yet, it won't obviously work because `files[0]` will throw an index out of range error.

Comment: IE9. I actully created customvalidator for the UploadFile control to checkt the file size.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng, IE9 is OK. As far as I know it supports this fnuctionality.

Comment: I got the files[0] is undefined.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng, did you select a file at the moment you tried to execute this code?

Comment: Yes. I put it in a javascript that gets called by OnClientClick in a submit button.

Comment: @GaolaiPeng, turns out IE9 doesn't support this yet. You could have been disappointed if that was the only HTML 5 API that IE9 doesn't support but since it's seriously lacking HTML 5 support, you cannot rely on client scripting with IE9 to verify that. I am sorry.

Comment: That is OK. Thanks for your help. So I guess there is no way I can solve the problem.